# How to import output from a dynamic Manipulate in NB1 to NB2?

Tags: manipulate, import, dataset, charts

I have the following Code which works fine:

```
ClearAll[fig1Akbar];
fig1Akbar = Manipulate[
  BarChart[
  {1, 6*e2, 3*e3, 9, 12*e5},
  PlotTheme -> "Business",
  FrameLabel -> {{HoldForm[Number of expected children], 
     None}, {HoldForm[Years], None}}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   HoldForm[
    Expected number of Derivative[1][Akbar] s children until40], 
  LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]},
  ImageSize -> 400
  ],

{e2, {-2, -1, 0, 2, 4}},
{e3, {1, 2, 3, 4}},
{e5, {-2, 0, -1, 1, 4}}
];

Save["myfig1Akbar", fig1Akbar];
```

With the above Code, I create a Manipulate and export it to NB2 by using Save[] command without any trouble.

However, if I use a dataset **Dataset** inside **Manipulate**, then I cannot see the dynamic output created in NB1 while in NB2. I tried to find answers from the Mathematica repository with no success.

```
ClearAll[data, fig2Akbar];
data =  Import["/Volumes/D/deneme.xlsx", {"Data", 1}];
data = data[[2 ;; 6, 1 ;; 3]];

fig2Akbar = Manipulate[
 BarChart[
 data[[All, col]],
  PlotTheme -> "Business",
FrameLabel -> {{HoldForm[Number of  expected children], 
   None}, {HoldForm[Years], None}}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
    HoldForm[
  Expected number of Derivative[1][Akbar] s children until40], 
  LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]},
  ImageSize -> 400
  ],
{col, {1, 2, 3}},
{c1, {-2, -1, 0, 2, 4}},
{c2, {1, 2, 3, 4}},
{c3, {-2, 0, -1, 1, 4}}
];

Save["myfig2Akbar", fig2Akbar]; (* in NB1 *)
Get["myfig2Akbar"]; (* in NB2 *)
```

My purpose is to dynamically see **dashboard=Manipulate[...]** in NB2 by **Save["mydashboard",dashboard]** in NB1 and **Get["mydashboard"]** in NB2. When I recall "Get[...]" in NB2, I do not see the dynamic bar charts in NB2 but see only the first item in **Dataset**.

If the actual dataset is necessary for an answer, please let me know so that I can provide you with the actual dataset.

Any help is appreciated!